# if-statement with nested multiple conditions

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to put multiple conditions in my if statement in Python like below:

```
if (h9 == h1 or h9 == h2 or h9 == h3 or h9 == h4 or h9 == h5 or h9 == h6 or h9 == h7 or h9 == h8) and (h10 == h1 or h10 == h2 or h10 == h3 or h10 == h4 or h10 == h5 or h10 == h6 or h10 == h7 or h10 == h8) :
     do sth.
```

Basically it's OR condition for both `h9` and `h10` at the same time.
However, this doesn't work, and gives errors like:

> `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

What's the problem?

Comment: If it's indentation, we will need more context...

Comment: Indentation and white space are [important to how Python interprets a script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Indentation). You'll need to make sure that you have tabs in the correct spaces, an editor that does it for you is really helpful.

Answer (score 7):

No idea about the indentation error without more context, but here's something you can do to make the `if` condition shorter:

```
lst = [h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8]
if h9 in lst and h10 in lst:
    pass
```

Also, you should really use more descriptive variable names.

---

Oh, and if you have a lot of elements and plan to do a lot of searching, you might favor sets:

```
s = set([h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8])    # {h1, h2, h3, ...} in Python 3.x
if h9 in s and h10 in s:
    pass
```

Comment: a little faster would be `lst = set([h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8])`

Comment: @PhilCooper A little slow, my friend :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you must use long conditionals, you can enclose your entire if condition in parenthesis, you can put it on multiple lines without indentation errors.

```
a = 2
b = 2
if ((a == 1 or a == 2) and 
        (b == 1 or b == 2)):
    print "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no indentation problem here.
I suppose that there is an indentation problem inside `do sth.`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
if any(h in {h1,h2,...} for h in (h9, h10)):
```

Comment: @PlatinumAzure I'm using sets: O(1) search

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: No, it creates a set in newer Python versions.

Comment: Damn it. I'm still using 2.6, sorry.

Comment: @JBernardo: Mistyped, meant 2.6

Comment: A list would be faster here.  Constructing a set for a *single* search operation is not useful (and this code recreates the set in ervery iteration).